# MongoDB find document matching a coordinate comparison

Tags: mongodb, nosql, geometry, coordinates

I am currently working on a mongoDB database for a class project. However, I'm very new to it.
I must find all documents where the latitude is greater than a certain value: 39. Longitude value can be anything.
Please find below the example of one document, showing the global structure of the database.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5gyg.png)

Looking at MongoDB's documentation, I have two hints:

- Trying a nested document query ("end station location.coordinates.0:{$gt:39})
  Yet, it is not working..
- Trying some geometric intersection. As I'm very new to MongoDB, I don't know if it'd be the easiest way to find what's I'm looking for.

Could someone help me improving myself ?

Regards,

Comment: Does `end station location.coordinates.0:{$gt:39}` works? It so, what's exactly the problem and the question?

Comment: Oh no sorry, I meant "not", not "now". I'm modifying it

Comment: And you want to look only for "end station location" field or also "start station location" too? And if almost one of them is true return the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is you are looking for values greater than 39 in the first position in the array. And these values in your example are negative numbers, so no one is grater than 39.

If you do the same query using `$lt` you will get results. Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BtQlvaOPIq4).

Also, to find values `$gt: 39` you have to find the second position into the array:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "end station location.coordinates.1": {
    "$gt": 39
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/svdYxAXqqKi)

Also, if you want to get the values if exists almost in one filed `end station location` or `start station location` you need `$or` operator like this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "end station location.coordinates.1": {
        "$gt": 39
      }
    },
    {
      "start station location.coordinates.1": {
        "$gt": 39
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W0HeuhVmo8_)

And remember, you want to search by second position into the array, so you have to use `coordinates.1`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answer. Everything is fine. Indeed I confused latitude and longitude. It's indeeed working. Moreover, thanks for the $or hint structure, it can be very useful in the future !

Comment: You are welcome! Hope it works and if the problem has been resolved, mark answer as accepted is apreciated.